# AngularJs filter $index

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

```
<input ng-model="searchData" />

<table>
    <tr class="odd" tr-mouse-over  ng-show="!allQualityDataLoading" ng-repeat="data  in tabListInfo track by $index| filter:searchData | orderBy:order : reverse" ng-init="outerIndex = $index">
         <td class="left">&nbsp;</td>
         <td class="left">
             <a ng-click="spreadDetail(spreadIDs[$index],tabname[$index])" href="javascript:void(0)">{{tabname[$index]}}</a>
         </td>
         <td ng-repeat="num in data track by $index">{{num}}<span ng-show="$index==3">%</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

this filter can not work,what should i do to make it work

Comment: I think the filter *can* work, but may not be working in your situation.  are you receiving an error, or seeing unexpected results?  This code doesn't tell us what the problem might be.

Comment: thanks~ I already found where the problem is, track by $index should be written in the end
data  in tabListInfo | filter:searchData track by $index